# waitUntilInstanceRunning in the AWS JS SDK hangs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm writing a small function to start and stop some of our AWS resources outside of office hours, based on [this article](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-eventbridge).

Currently my code looks like this - edited for brevity.

```js
import { EC2Client, StartInstancesCommand, waitUntilInstanceRunning } from '@aws-sdk/client-ec2';
import { ElasticLoadBalancingV2Client, RegisterTargetsCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-elastic-load-balancing-v2";

// ...get the InstanceIds of EC2 instances to start...

const startEC2Command = new StartInstancesCommand({ InstanceIds });
const startEC2Response = await ec2Client.send(startEC2Command);

await waitUntilInstanceRunning({}, {
  Filters: [
    {
      Name: 'instance-id',
      Values: [
        STAGING_API_SERVER_EC2_ID,
      ],
    },
  ],
});

const registerTargetsCommand = new RegisterTargetsCommand({
  TargetGroupArn: STAGING_TG_ARN,
  Targets: [
    {
      Id: STAGING_API_SERVER_EC2_ID,
      Port: 4000,
    }
  ]
});

const registerTargetResponse = await elbv2Client.send(registerTargetsCommand);
// ... starts more resources, RDS etc.
```

Previously, my code was failing because register targets only works if the EC2 instance is in the running state, so I added `waitUntilInstanceRunning` to ensure that the instance is running before it tries to register with the target group. For some reason, the script hangs at the line await waitUntilInstanceRunning, even when the AWS console shows that the instance is in fact running.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-ec2/Variable/waitUntilInstanceRunning/) for this command is sparse to say the least, so does anyone know how to use it correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to pass the ec2Client in WaiterConfiguration like below.

```js
await waitUntilInstanceRunning(
  { client: ec2Client }, 
  {
    Filters: [
      {
        Name: 'instance-id',
        Values: [
          STAGING_API_SERVER_EC2_ID,
        ],
      },
    ],
  });
```

WaiterConfiguration: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-smithy-types/Interface/WaiterConfiguration/